# Вопросы по Objective-c

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

У меня несколько вопросов :

1. Какая разница между написанием @synthesize var и @synthesize var = _var;
2. Чем ivar отличается от проперти?

Спасибо

Comment: MM тут какбы не при чем, это просто разные вещи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@synthesize var` -- то же, что и `@synthesize var = var`.

Определяет property var, используя для хранения значения instance-переменную var. (Её-то и называют ivar) Для случая `@synthesize var = _var`, используется, понятно, instance-переменная _var.

Теперь в чём отличие. Когда вы декларируете property, вы на самом деле неявно определяете две функции: геттер (которая возвращает наружу значение property) и сеттер (которая устанавливает). Простейшая имплементация геттера и сеттера -- просто читать из какой-нибудь переменной, и записывать в неё. Но они могут также делать более сложные вещи: retain/release, запись в log, что угодно. Когда вы пишете `@synthesize var = _var`, вы говорите, что эта самая переменная будет называться _var, на случай если вы захотите прочитать её сами.

Заметьте, что если изнутри класса вы говорите `self.var`, вы получаете обращение к property: вы получаете, конечно, то значение, которое записано в ivar, но дополнительно происходят те вещи, которые определены в геттере. Если же вы пользуетесь нотацией `var`, вы получаете именно переменную, в обход геттера. Всё ясно?

Теперь смотрите, зачем нужны property. Дело в том, что для public-переменной вы не можете контролировать её использование. Например, вы не сможете открыть переменную только на чтение. Или не сможете убедиться, что все, кто использует переменную, правильно делают retain. Поэтому хорошим стилем является давать доступ к переменным через property, а переменные прятать.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а то была путаница

Comment: @Dmitry99: пожалуйста!

Answer (score -2):

1) _var "должен" быть private.
var это проперти для _var
его ( _var) следует указывать явно при кастомном написании проперти `(setIvar:)`
 по дефолту `@synthesize var` , скажем так, эквивалкентно `@synthesize var = _var;`

2) [Wiki свойства](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B0)

Comment: Он не должен быть приватным, он может быть хоть публичным.

Comment: @1101_debian: именно поэтому слово должен было взято в скобки.
это практика хорошая.
для того, чтоб ему быть "хоть публичным" и есть отчасти заслуга property